# lspci shows devices without names, but it did on other OS version with the same kernel

Tags: intel, devices, lspci

I found out after installation Kubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.13 that `lspci` can't identify devices. Now it looks so:

```
$ lspci
0:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a14 (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a09 (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a23 (rev 01)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a27 (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 9a11 (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a13 (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1b (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1d (rev 01)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a0fc (rev 20)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a0ed (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a0ef (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a0f0 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e8 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e9 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e0 (rev 20)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0c5 (rev 20)
00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0c6 (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b3 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a082 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a0a3 (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0a4 (rev 20)
```

It worth to notice when i installed and tested Kubuntu 21.10 with kernel 5.13 they were identified correctly.

What can be wrong and does it affect operating system functioning?

Comment: So what is the problem? Run `lspci -k` and you'll see if modules are loaded. All devices are detected.

Comment: Ok, Take a look at the output and tell me please what a wifi card is there ? No names on Kubuntu 20.04, but they are on Kubuntu 21.10

Comment: Run `dmesg | grep iwl` and you'll see.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I clearly wrote in the title that 'lspci` doesn't show names but it has to, which i need to check my laptop hardware.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter if lspci shows "names" or not. I don't remember if `lspci` or other package contains these human readable names. Obviously the 20.10 release has a newer package. But this doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: Try to run `sudo update-pciids`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. The 21.10 release has newer packages that contain human readable device names. That's the reason why it has names for new hardware.

The names are stored in `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids`.

You can update the list by

```
sudo update-pciids
```

But Linux kernel doesn't rely on it in any way. So it doesn't affect how the OS works.

Comment: Great. Could your recommend a way to list all the devices with their names?

Comment: Run `sudo update-pciids` and try again.

Comment: That works. I think it worth to update the answer with this command.